# cannot fill autocomplete with data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

```
var first = true;
var json = '[';
if (!first) {
    json += ',';
} else {
    first = false;
}
// $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
json += '{label:"kasun"}';


json += ']';
console.log(json);
$("#p_name").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: x,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $("#p_name").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        return false;
    }
})
```

i tried above code to populate auto complete with data.when i try this i get following error.
if u have alternative please let me know

```
    GET http://localhost/NEW/patient_channel/[%7Blabel:%22kasun%22%7D]?term=ka 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Are you expecting the autocomplete framework to try to get a list of potential autocomplete results from your server, or is this unexpected behavior all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source should be an array, not a string

You need

```
var json = [];

// $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
json.push({label:"kasun", value:"kasun"})
//or json.push('kasun')

//});

console.log(json);

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#p_name").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: json,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#p_name").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3mwpY/) or [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3mwpY/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your source x is not visible elsewhere in the code, I believe its a URL and since it is giving 404 as mentioned by tou, means the resource doesn not exist on server.

Fix the 404 first, after that you have to format the data returned by server in format expected by autocomplete as follows.

```
[{'label' : dataValue, 'value' : dataValue}]
```